# How can I recursively update object properties in hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the below function in order to recursively display IP subnets by user click:

```
const traverse = (o: any) => {
  return o.map((item: any, key: number) => {
    let extra = item.hasOwnProperty("extra") ? item.extra : item;
    return (
      <TreeItem
        key={key}
        nodeId={extra.id}
        icon={item.has_child ? <ChevronLeftIcon /> : ""}
        label={item.subnet}
        onClick={
          extra.has_child ? (e) => loadChildren(extra, extra.id) : () => ""
        }
      >
        {item.child ? traverse(item.child) : ""}
      </TreeItem>
    );
  });
};
```

Now I have put the fetch action in  `loadChildren` where I would set the newly fetched data:

```
const loadChildren = (extra: any, id: number | string) => {
  setLoadingChildren(true);
  getIpState(id)
    .then((res) => {
      setRows({
        ...rows,
        data: rows.data.map((item: any) =>
          item.id == id ? { ...item, child: res.data } : item
        ),
      });
      setLoadingChildren(false);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      setLoadingChildren(false);
    });
};
```

Now the question is, how can I iterate through `child: res.data` and add their own `child: res.data` having the response of newly fetched data?

Comment: I think I know what you want to do but I'm not quiet sure how to set it up to test on it. Could you please provide a runnable snippet? Thanks!

Comment: I would appreciate a brief insight on that, no need to test it.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I'm just bad at debugging code by just looking at it, but maybe someone else is able to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was solved like this:

```
  const findClickedItem = (items: any,res: any,id:any) => {
  return items.map((item: any) => {
          let extra = item.hasOwnProperty('extra') ? item.extra : item
          return extra.id == id ? {
              ...item,
              child: res.data
          } : item.hasOwnProperty('child')
              ? {...item, child: findClickedItem(item.child, res, id)} : item
      }
  ) 
}
```

And is used in `loadChildren` like this:

```
  const loadChildren = (id: number | string) => {
      setLoadingChildren(true)
      getIpState(id).then(res=> {
          setRows({
              ...rows,
              data: findClickedItem(rows.data, res, id)
          })
          setLoadingChildren(false)
      }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
          setLoadingChildren(false)
      })
  }
```